# Sharepoint 2010 Foundation SBS 2011 email error sending email

Tags: sharepoint, smtp, moss

I have installed SBS 2011 and running sharepoint 2010 foundation. I have created an intranet site. my question is related to the one on this link: [error while sending mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528432/error-while-sending-mail)

but my problem is that I get the same error even when I add users in my domain. their email are captured correctly. I believe that I have correctly configured the outgoing email option on the central administration system settings. I have also used SMPTtest tool to test these settings and the email is delivered, meaning my email infrastructure is right.

the erroe says: "***The user or users have been added successfully, but there was an error in sending the e-mail message. The server may not be set up correctly to send e-mail. To verify that e-mail is configured correctly, contact your server administrator.***"

I when I set alerts, I do not get the confirmation alert or any alert when anything changes on the particular list.

At this point, I don't know what to do. I have tried restarting the Sharepoint Timer service, IIS, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check that your smtp server is setup in Central Admin > Outgoign email settings. Verify BOTH the farm and web application settings.

1a) Check the FROM address has been set.

2) verify the users have the correct SMTP address

3) Use SMTPTest Tool / Telnet to send a test email to the same SMTP server in 1 using an address from 2)

I konw you've said you've done this but you've likely missed something - http://sharepointalert.info/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts/

Comment: How do I verify the "Farm and web application settings"? I have checked that the central Admin >Outgoing Email is configured correctly and I used SMTPTest to test the same settings, and they worked with the SMTP test. On the link: http://sharepointalert.info/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts/ I have tested the infrustructure and I believe it works fine. How do I check the Sharepoint Timer Jobs?

Comment: If you don't get the Confirmation emails then the problem isn't to do with timer jobs. Have you checked outgoing email at the farm and web application level? Upload screenshots. Do you have anti-virus running on your server, tried disabling it?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the outgoing mail on both the farm and web application levels... I have also tried disabling the antivirus, but I get the same error. How do I go about posting screenshot?

Comment: I use Small Business Server 2011 with come inbuilt with Sharepoint Foundation 2010. When I set up Outgoing email at the server level, the settings automatically propagate to the application level. I have checked the outgoing email settings at the application level, and the info is the same as that at the farm level; same Outbound SMTP server, from address, reply-to address and same Character set. I just don't know how to post screen short here